# ATmega 2560 adding additional interrupt to to pin config file

Tags: arduino

I am using an ATmega2560 on a custom PCB. I've wired PE6 and PE7 and interrupts however, since these two pins where never wired on an Arduino board, the pins where never configured in the pins.arduino.h file. I'd like to add PE6 and PE7 to the pin configuration file to use as an interrupt. I've opened the file but I am unable to decipher what I need to do to modify the file. I believe I've narrowed it down to a single line:

```cpp
#define digitalPinToInterrupt(p) ((p) == 2 ? 0 : ((p) == 3 ? 1 : ((p) >= 18 && (p) <= 21 ? 23 - (p) : NOT_AN_INTERRUPT)))
```

Just not sure what I need to add to include the two interrupts.

Can someone walk me through what I need to add?

Here is the entire pin file that I am currently using:

```cpp
#ifndef Pins_Arduino_h
#define Pins_Arduino_h

#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

#define NUM_DIGITAL_PINS            70
#define NUM_ANALOG_INPUTS           16
#define analogInputToDigitalPin(p)  ((p < 16) ? (p) + 54 : -1)
#define digitalPinHasPWM(p)         (((p) >= 2 && (p) <= 13) || ((p) >= 44 && (p)<= 46))

#define PIN_SPI_SS    (53)
#define PIN_SPI_MOSI  (51)
#define PIN_SPI_MISO  (50)
#define PIN_SPI_SCK   (52)

static const uint8_t SS   = PIN_SPI_SS;
static const uint8_t MOSI = PIN_SPI_MOSI;
static const uint8_t MISO = PIN_SPI_MISO;
static const uint8_t SCK  = PIN_SPI_SCK;

#define PIN_WIRE_SDA        (20)
#define PIN_WIRE_SCL        (21)

static const uint8_t SDA = PIN_WIRE_SDA;
static const uint8_t SCL = PIN_WIRE_SCL;

#define LED_BUILTIN 13

#define PIN_A0   (54)
#define PIN_A1   (55)
#define PIN_A2   (56)
#define PIN_A3   (57)
#define PIN_A4   (58)
#define PIN_A5   (59)
#define PIN_A6   (60)
#define PIN_A7   (61)
#define PIN_A8   (62)
#define PIN_A9   (63)
#define PIN_A10  (64)
#define PIN_A11  (65)
#define PIN_A12  (66)
#define PIN_A13  (67)
#define PIN_A14  (68)
#define PIN_A15  (69)

static const uint8_t A0 = PIN_A0;
static const uint8_t A1 = PIN_A1;
static const uint8_t A2 = PIN_A2;
static const uint8_t A3 = PIN_A3;
static const uint8_t A4 = PIN_A4;
static const uint8_t A5 = PIN_A5;
static const uint8_t A6 = PIN_A6;
static const uint8_t A7 = PIN_A7;
static const uint8_t A8 = PIN_A8;
static const uint8_t A9 = PIN_A9;
static const uint8_t A10 = PIN_A10;
static const uint8_t A11 = PIN_A11;
static const uint8_t A12 = PIN_A12;
static const uint8_t A13 = PIN_A13;
static const uint8_t A14 = PIN_A14;
static const uint8_t A15 = PIN_A15;

// A majority of the pins are NOT PCINTs, SO BE WARNED (i.e. you cannot use them as receive pins)
// Only pins available for RECEIVE (TRANSMIT can be on any pin):
// (I've deliberately left out pin mapping to the Hardware USARTs - seems senseless to me)
// Pins: 10, 11, 12, 13,  50, 51, 52, 53,  62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69

#define digitalPinToPCICR(p)    ( (((p) >= 10) && ((p) <= 13)) || \
                                  (((p) >= 50) && ((p) <= 53)) || \
                                  (((p) >= 62) && ((p) <= 69)) ? (&PCICR) : ((uint8_t *)0) )

#define digitalPinToPCICRbit(p) ( (((p) >= 10) && ((p) <= 13)) || (((p) >= 50) && ((p) <= 53)) ? 0 : \
                                ( (((p) >= 62) && ((p) <= 69)) ? 2 : \
                                0 ) )

#define digitalPinToPCMSK(p)    ( (((p) >= 10) && ((p) <= 13)) || (((p) >= 50) && ((p) <= 53)) ? (&PCMSK0) : \
                                ( (((p) >= 62) && ((p) <= 69)) ? (&PCMSK2) : \
                                ((uint8_t *)0) ) )

#define digitalPinToPCMSKbit(p) ( (((p) >= 10) && ((p) <= 13)) ? ((p) - 6) : \
                                ( ((p) == 50) ? 3 : \
                                ( ((p) == 51) ? 2 : \
                                ( ((p) == 52) ? 1 : \
                                ( ((p) == 53) ? 0 : \
                                ( (((p) >= 62) && ((p) <= 69)) ? ((p) - 62) : \
                                0 ) ) ) ) ) )

#define digitalPinToInterrupt(p) ((p) == 2 ? 0 : ((p) == 3 ? 1 : ((p) >= 18 && (p) <= 21 ? 23 - (p) : NOT_AN_INTERRUPT)))

#ifdef ARDUINO_MAIN

const uint16_t PROGMEM port_to_mode_PGM[] = {
    NOT_A_PORT,
    (uint16_t) &DDRA,
    (uint16_t) &DDRB,
    (uint16_t) &DDRC,
    (uint16_t) &DDRD,
    (uint16_t) &DDRE,
    (uint16_t) &DDRF,
    (uint16_t) &DDRG,
    (uint16_t) &DDRH,
    NOT_A_PORT,
    (uint16_t) &DDRJ,
    (uint16_t) &DDRK,
    (uint16_t) &DDRL,
};

const uint16_t PROGMEM port_to_output_PGM[] = {
    NOT_A_PORT,
    (uint16_t) &PORTA,
    (uint16_t) &PORTB,
    (uint16_t) &PORTC,
    (uint16_t) &PORTD,
    (uint16_t) &PORTE,
    (uint16_t) &PORTF,
    (uint16_t) &PORTG,
    (uint16_t) &PORTH,
    NOT_A_PORT,
    (uint16_t) &PORTJ,
    (uint16_t) &PORTK,
    (uint16_t) &PORTL,
};

const uint16_t PROGMEM port_to_input_PGM[] = {
    NOT_A_PIN,
    (uint16_t) &PINA,
    (uint16_t) &PINB,
    (uint16_t) &PINC,
    (uint16_t) &PIND,
    (uint16_t) &PINE,
    (uint16_t) &PINF,
    (uint16_t) &PING,
    (uint16_t) &PINH,
    NOT_A_PIN,
    (uint16_t) &PINJ,
    (uint16_t) &PINK,
    (uint16_t) &PINL,
};

const uint8_t PROGMEM digital_pin_to_port_PGM[] = {
    // PORTLIST             
    // -------------------------------------------          
    PE  , // PE 0 ** 0 ** USART0_RX     
    PE  , // PE 1 ** 1 ** USART0_TX     
    PE  , // PE 4 ** 2 ** PWM2  
    PE  , // PE 5 ** 3 ** PWM3  
    PG  , // PG 5 ** 4 ** PWM4  
    PE  , // PE 3 ** 5 ** PWM5  
    PH  , // PH 3 ** 6 ** PWM6  
    PH  , // PH 4 ** 7 ** PWM7  
    PH  , // PH 5 ** 8 ** PWM8  
    PH  , // PH 6 ** 9 ** PWM9  
    PB  , // PB 4 ** 10 ** PWM10        
    PB  , // PB 5 ** 11 ** PWM11        
    PB  , // PB 6 ** 12 ** PWM12        
    PB  , // PB 7 ** 13 ** PWM13        
    PJ  , // PJ 1 ** 14 ** USART3_TX    
    PJ  , // PJ 0 ** 15 ** USART3_RX    
    PH  , // PH 1 ** 16 ** USART2_TX    
    PH  , // PH 0 ** 17 ** USART2_RX    
    PD  , // PD 3 ** 18 ** USART1_TX    
    PD  , // PD 2 ** 19 ** USART1_RX    
    PD  , // PD 1 ** 20 ** I2C_SDA      
    PD  , // PD 0 ** 21 ** I2C_SCL      
    PA  , // PA 0 ** 22 ** D22  
    PA  , // PA 1 ** 23 ** D23  
    PA  , // PA 2 ** 24 ** D24  
    PA  , // PA 3 ** 25 ** D25  
    PA  , // PA 4 ** 26 ** D26  
    PA  , // PA 5 ** 27 ** D27  
    PA  , // PA 6 ** 28 ** D28  
    PA  , // PA 7 ** 29 ** D29  
    PC  , // PC 7 ** 30 ** D30  
    PC  , // PC 6 ** 31 ** D31  
    PC  , // PC 5 ** 32 ** D32  
    PC  , // PC 4 ** 33 ** D33  
    PC  , // PC 3 ** 34 ** D34  
    PC  , // PC 2 ** 35 ** D35  
    PC  , // PC 1 ** 36 ** D36  
    PC  , // PC 0 ** 37 ** D37  
    PD  , // PD 7 ** 38 ** D38  
    PG  , // PG 2 ** 39 ** D39  
    PG  , // PG 1 ** 40 ** D40  
    PG  , // PG 0 ** 41 ** D41  
    PL  , // PL 7 ** 42 ** D42  
    PL  , // PL 6 ** 43 ** D43  
    PL  , // PL 5 ** 44 ** D44  
    PL  , // PL 4 ** 45 ** D45  
    PL  , // PL 3 ** 46 ** D46  
    PL  , // PL 2 ** 47 ** D47  
    PL  , // PL 1 ** 48 ** D48  
    PL  , // PL 0 ** 49 ** D49  
    PB  , // PB 3 ** 50 ** SPI_MISO     
    PB  , // PB 2 ** 51 ** SPI_MOSI     
    PB  , // PB 1 ** 52 ** SPI_SCK      
    PB  , // PB 0 ** 53 ** SPI_SS       
    PF  , // PF 0 ** 54 ** A0   
    PF  , // PF 1 ** 55 ** A1   
    PF  , // PF 2 ** 56 ** A2   
    PF  , // PF 3 ** 57 ** A3   
    PF  , // PF 4 ** 58 ** A4   
    PF  , // PF 5 ** 59 ** A5   
    PF  , // PF 6 ** 60 ** A6   
    PF  , // PF 7 ** 61 ** A7   
    PK  , // PK 0 ** 62 ** A8   
    PK  , // PK 1 ** 63 ** A9   
    PK  , // PK 2 ** 64 ** A10  
    PK  , // PK 3 ** 65 ** A11  
    PK  , // PK 4 ** 66 ** A12  
    PK  , // PK 5 ** 67 ** A13  
    PK  , // PK 6 ** 68 ** A14  
    PK  , // PK 7 ** 69 ** A15  
    // added stuff
    PD  , // PD 4 ** 70 ** D70
    PD  , // PD 5 ** 71 ** D71
    PD  , // PD 6 ** 72 ** D72
    PG  , // PG 3 ** 73 ** D73
    PG  , // PG 4 ** 74 ** D74
    PH  , // PH 2 ** 75 ** D75
    PH  , // PH 7 ** 76 ** D76
    PJ  , // PJ 2 ** 77 ** D77
    PJ  , // PJ 3 ** 78 ** D78
    PJ  , // PJ 4 ** 79 ** D79
    PJ  , // PJ 5 ** 80 ** D80
    PJ  , // PJ 6 ** 81 ** D81
    PJ  , // PJ 7 ** 82 ** D82
    PE  , // PE 6 ** 83 ** D83
    PE  , // PE 7 ** 84 ** D84
};

const uint8_t PROGMEM digital_pin_to_bit_mask_PGM[] = {
    // PIN IN PORT          
    // -------------------------------------------          
    _BV( 0 )    , // PE 0 ** 0 ** USART0_RX     
    _BV( 1 )    , // PE 1 ** 1 ** USART0_TX     
    _BV( 4 )    , // PE 4 ** 2 ** PWM2  
    _BV( 5 )    , // PE 5 ** 3 ** PWM3  
    _BV( 5 )    , // PG 5 ** 4 ** PWM4  
    _BV( 3 )    , // PE 3 ** 5 ** PWM5  
    _BV( 3 )    , // PH 3 ** 6 ** PWM6  
    _BV( 4 )    , // PH 4 ** 7 ** PWM7  
    _BV( 5 )    , // PH 5 ** 8 ** PWM8  
    _BV( 6 )    , // PH 6 ** 9 ** PWM9  
    _BV( 4 )    , // PB 4 ** 10 ** PWM10        
    _BV( 5 )    , // PB 5 ** 11 ** PWM11        
    _BV( 6 )    , // PB 6 ** 12 ** PWM12        
    _BV( 7 )    , // PB 7 ** 13 ** PWM13        
    _BV( 1 )    , // PJ 1 ** 14 ** USART3_TX    
    _BV( 0 )    , // PJ 0 ** 15 ** USART3_RX    
    _BV( 1 )    , // PH 1 ** 16 ** USART2_TX    
    _BV( 0 )    , // PH 0 ** 17 ** USART2_RX    
    _BV( 3 )    , // PD 3 ** 18 ** USART1_TX    
    _BV( 2 )    , // PD 2 ** 19 ** USART1_RX    
    _BV( 1 )    , // PD 1 ** 20 ** I2C_SDA      
    _BV( 0 )    , // PD 0 ** 21 ** I2C_SCL      
    _BV( 0 )    , // PA 0 ** 22 ** D22  
    _BV( 1 )    , // PA 1 ** 23 ** D23  
    _BV( 2 )    , // PA 2 ** 24 ** D24  
    _BV( 3 )    , // PA 3 ** 25 ** D25  
    _BV( 4 )    , // PA 4 ** 26 ** D26  
    _BV( 5 )    , // PA 5 ** 27 ** D27  
    _BV( 6 )    , // PA 6 ** 28 ** D28  
    _BV( 7 )    , // PA 7 ** 29 ** D29  
    _BV( 7 )    , // PC 7 ** 30 ** D30  
    _BV( 6 )    , // PC 6 ** 31 ** D31  
    _BV( 5 )    , // PC 5 ** 32 ** D32  
    _BV( 4 )    , // PC 4 ** 33 ** D33  
    _BV( 3 )    , // PC 3 ** 34 ** D34  
    _BV( 2 )    , // PC 2 ** 35 ** D35  
    _BV( 1 )    , // PC 1 ** 36 ** D36  
    _BV( 0 )    , // PC 0 ** 37 ** D37  
    _BV( 7 )    , // PD 7 ** 38 ** D38  
    _BV( 2 )    , // PG 2 ** 39 ** D39  
    _BV( 1 )    , // PG 1 ** 40 ** D40  
    _BV( 0 )    , // PG 0 ** 41 ** D41  
    _BV( 7 )    , // PL 7 ** 42 ** D42  
    _BV( 6 )    , // PL 6 ** 43 ** D43  
    _BV( 5 )    , // PL 5 ** 44 ** D44  
    _BV( 4 )    , // PL 4 ** 45 ** D45
    _BV( 3 )    , // PL 3 ** 46 ** D46  
    _BV( 2 )    , // PL 2 ** 47 ** D47  
    _BV( 1 )    , // PL 1 ** 48 ** D48  
    _BV( 0 )    , // PL 0 ** 49 ** D49  
    _BV( 3 )    , // PB 3 ** 50 ** SPI_MISO     
    _BV( 2 )    , // PB 2 ** 51 ** SPI_MOSI     
    _BV( 1 )    , // PB 1 ** 52 ** SPI_SCK      
    _BV( 0 )    , // PB 0 ** 53 ** SPI_SS       
    _BV( 0 )    , // PF 0 ** 54 ** A0   
    _BV( 1 )    , // PF 1 ** 55 ** A1   
    _BV( 2 )    , // PF 2 ** 56 ** A2   
    _BV( 3 )    , // PF 3 ** 57 ** A3   
    _BV( 4 )    , // PF 4 ** 58 ** A4   
    _BV( 5 )    , // PF 5 ** 59 ** A5   
    _BV( 6 )    , // PF 6 ** 60 ** A6   
    _BV( 7 )    , // PF 7 ** 61 ** A7   
    _BV( 0 )    , // PK 0 ** 62 ** A8   
    _BV( 1 )    , // PK 1 ** 63 ** A9   
    _BV( 2 )    , // PK 2 ** 64 ** A10  
    _BV( 3 )    , // PK 3 ** 65 ** A11  
    _BV( 4 )    , // PK 4 ** 66 ** A12  
    _BV( 5 )    , // PK 5 ** 67 ** A13  
    _BV( 6 )    , // PK 6 ** 68 ** A14  
    _BV( 7 )    , // PK 7 ** 69 ** A15  
    // added stuff
    _BV( 4 )    , // PD 4 ** 70 ** D70
    _BV( 5 )    , // PD 5 ** 71 ** D71
    _BV( 6 )    , // PD 6 ** 72 ** D72
    _BV( 3 )    , // PG 3 ** 73 ** D73
    _BV( 4 )    , // PG 4 ** 74 ** D74
    _BV( 2 )    , // PH 2 ** 75 ** D75
    _BV( 7 )    , // PH 7 ** 76 ** D76
    _BV( 2 )    , // PJ 2 ** 77 ** D77
    _BV( 3 )    , // PJ 3 ** 78 ** D78
    _BV( 4 )    , // PJ 4 ** 79 ** D79
    _BV( 5 )    , // PJ 5 ** 80 ** D80
    _BV( 6 )    , // PJ 6 ** 81 ** D81
    _BV( 7 )    , // PJ 7 ** 82 ** D82
    _BV( 6 )    , // PE 6 ** 83 ** D83
    _BV( 7 )    , // PE 7 ** 84 ** D84
};

const uint8_t PROGMEM digital_pin_to_timer_PGM[] = {
    // TIMERS               
    // -------------------------------------------          
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PE 0 ** 0 ** USART0_RX     
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PE 1 ** 1 ** USART0_TX     
    TIMER3B , // PE 4 ** 2 ** PWM2  
    TIMER3C , // PE 5 ** 3 ** PWM3  
    TIMER0B , // PG 5 ** 4 ** PWM4  
    TIMER3A , // PE 3 ** 5 ** PWM5  
    TIMER4A , // PH 3 ** 6 ** PWM6  
    TIMER4B , // PH 4 ** 7 ** PWM7  
    TIMER4C , // PH 5 ** 8 ** PWM8  
    TIMER2B , // PH 6 ** 9 ** PWM9  
    TIMER2A , // PB 4 ** 10 ** PWM10        
    TIMER1A , // PB 5 ** 11 ** PWM11        
    TIMER1B , // PB 6 ** 12 ** PWM12        
    TIMER0A , // PB 7 ** 13 ** PWM13        
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PJ 1 ** 14 ** USART3_TX    
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PJ 0 ** 15 ** USART3_RX    
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PH 1 ** 16 ** USART2_TX    
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PH 0 ** 17 ** USART2_RX    
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PD 3 ** 18 ** USART1_TX    
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PD 2 ** 19 ** USART1_RX    
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PD 1 ** 20 ** I2C_SDA      
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PD 0 ** 21 ** I2C_SCL      
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PA 0 ** 22 ** D22  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PA 1 ** 23 ** D23  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PA 2 ** 24 ** D24  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PA 3 ** 25 ** D25  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PA 4 ** 26 ** D26  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PA 5 ** 27 ** D27  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PA 6 ** 28 ** D28  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PA 7 ** 29 ** D29  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PC 7 ** 30 ** D30  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PC 6 ** 31 ** D31  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PC 5 ** 32 ** D32  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PC 4 ** 33 ** D33  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PC 3 ** 34 ** D34  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PC 2 ** 35 ** D35  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PC 1 ** 36 ** D36  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PC 0 ** 37 ** D37  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PD 7 ** 38 ** D38  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PG 2 ** 39 ** D39  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PG 1 ** 40 ** D40  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PG 0 ** 41 ** D41  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PL 7 ** 42 ** D42  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PL 6 ** 43 ** D43  
    TIMER5C , // PL 5 ** 44 ** D44  
    TIMER5B , // PL 4 ** 45 ** D45  
    TIMER5A , // PL 3 ** 46 ** D46  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PL 2 ** 47 ** D47  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PL 1 ** 48 ** D48  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PL 0 ** 49 ** D49  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PB 3 ** 50 ** SPI_MISO     
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PB 2 ** 51 ** SPI_MOSI     
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PB 1 ** 52 ** SPI_SCK      
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PB 0 ** 53 ** SPI_SS       
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PF 0 ** 54 ** A0   
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PF 1 ** 55 ** A1   
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PF 2 ** 56 ** A2   
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PF 3 ** 57 ** A3   
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PF 4 ** 58 ** A4   
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PF 5 ** 59 ** A5   
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PF 6 ** 60 ** A6   
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PF 7 ** 61 ** A7   
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PK 0 ** 62 ** A8   
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PK 1 ** 63 ** A9   
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PK 2 ** 64 ** A10  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PK 3 ** 65 ** A11  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PK 4 ** 66 ** A12  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PK 5 ** 67 ** A13  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PK 6 ** 68 ** A14  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PK 7 ** 69 ** A15  
    // added stuff
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PD 4 ** 70 ** D70
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PD 5 ** 71 ** D71
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PD 6 ** 72 ** D72
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PG 3 ** 73 ** D73
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PG 4 ** 74 ** D74
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PH 2 ** 75 ** D75
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PH 7 ** 76 ** D76
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PJ 2 ** 77 ** D77   // PCINT 11
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PJ 3 ** 78 ** D78   // PCINT 12
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PJ 4 ** 79 ** D79   // PCINT 13
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PJ 5 ** 80 ** D80   // PCINT 14
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PJ 6 ** 81 ** D81   // PCINT 15
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PJ 7 ** 82 ** D82
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PE 6 ** 83 ** D83
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PE 7 ** 84 ** D84
};

#endif

// These serial port names are intended to allow libraries and architecture-neutral
// sketches to automatically default to the correct port name for a particular type
// of use.  For example, a GPS module would normally connect to SERIAL_PORT_HARDWARE_OPEN,
// the first hardware serial port whose RX/TX pins are not dedicated to another use.
//
// SERIAL_PORT_MONITOR        Port which normally prints to the Arduino Serial Monitor
//
// SERIAL_PORT_USBVIRTUAL     Port which is USB virtual serial
//
// SERIAL_PORT_LINUXBRIDGE    Port which connects to a Linux system via Bridge library
//
// SERIAL_PORT_HARDWARE       Hardware serial port, physical RX & TX pins.
//
// SERIAL_PORT_HARDWARE_OPEN  Hardware serial ports which are open for use.  Their RX & TX
//                            pins are NOT connected to anything by default.
#define SERIAL_PORT_MONITOR         Serial
#define SERIAL_PORT_HARDWARE        Serial
#define SERIAL_PORT_HARDWARE1       Serial1
#define SERIAL_PORT_HARDWARE2       Serial2
#define SERIAL_PORT_HARDWARE3       Serial3
#define SERIAL_PORT_HARDWARE_OPEN   Serial1
#define SERIAL_PORT_HARDWARE_OPEN1  Serial2
#define SERIAL_PORT_HARDWARE_OPEN2  Serial3

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

From your pins file, it looks like PE6 and PE7 are pin numbers 83 and 84.
In that digitalPinToInterrupt() macro, replace the NOT_AN_INTERRUPT with
something like:

```
 ((p) == 83) ? 6 : ((p) == 84) ? 7 : NOT_AN_INTERRUPT
```

Replace the 6 and 7 with whatever interrupt numbers you need.

I don't know if that's all you'll need. It seems like there would be more
support for getting code associated with the interrupt vector.